# Coldfusion: Detecting if being run by the scheduler

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way for a ColdFusion app to know whether it is being run from the scheduler vs. from a browser?  Ideally, I'd like to set a Session flag, for instance "isScheduled" in Application.cfm to be used throughout the app.

***EDIT***
I ended up checking the user agent, and that it is being run locally (to improve security), and (since it is running in Application.cfm) that the page is in the folder which allows scheduling:

`Request.isScheduled = FindNoCase("CFSCHEDULE",CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT) 
                       and (Find("10.",CGI.REMOTE_ADDR)==1 
                            or Find("198.162.",CGI.REMOTE_ADDR)==1)
                       and FindNoCase("scheduled",CGI.CF_TEMPLATE_PATH);`

Comment: Why can't you simply pass a query string parameter and make the decision on that?

Comment: One of the uses for the flag would be to bypass user authentication (which uses a redirect to an enterprise-level central authentication service page) when being run by the scheduler, but require the authentication all other times.  Although I would be the only one who knows the query parameter to include, it would open a possible avenue for hacking, which I would rather avoid.

Comment: Checking the User Agent isn't any more secure. I can easily change my user agent in FireFox - theres even an add-on User Agent Switcher to make it easy to change. I do this all the time for testing.

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for the user agent.  The user agent is "CFSCHEDULE" but please confirm this first.

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  What I ended up with was: Request.isScheduled = FindNoCase("CFSCHEDULE",CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT);

Answer (score 1):

I nest my Application.cfm logic in a cfif, that checks to see if a parameter ('cron') is defined. If it is, then it skips all of the rest of the logic in Application like authentication, header crap, etc.

Then when I set up the scheduled tasks I pass in the URL I want to hit with the cron parameter (http://mysite.com/scheduledtasks.cfm?cron=yo)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if application run through scheduler then cgi.remote_address must be same for all request that you can track.....and mark "isSchedule"....

Comment: However, if you port code to a different server, you must hand-code that server.  I ended up checking http_user_agent AND checking remote_address to see if it was local (see code in edit to original question).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common practice to let the task scheduler run a list of tasks which in tern trigger the actual tasks. I.e. you ran "dailytask.cfm which cfincludes the task that you want to run. You can now add url.parameters or other things to it to identify the source of the trigger.