# Is there any way to make a page only callable by the ColdFusion admin?

Tags: coldfusion, admin

I have a scheduled task set up in my coldfusion server admin - every day at a specific time, it calls a certain page on the server.

The problem is, I don't want this page to be accidentally invoked by someone navigating to it in a browser. Is there any way to make sure that it can *only* be called by the CF admin?

Comment: Wouldn't restricting access to local IP addresses only work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `cgi.http_user_agent` - it should be `cfschedule` when called from within cfide or by the schedule.

I'm not sure if there is any documentation however it is something we have relied on under both CF8 and CF9. It's not a `servicefactory` command - it is the user agent used by the ColdFusion scheduler. [Also see answers to this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790834)

Note that it can be spoofed - any browser or http agent capable of setting it's own user agent would pass a test based solely on this value. Consider also using other tests like the the ip address, etc.

An added protection/obfuscation could be to require a specific url parameter (or a series of parameters) which could be hardcoded into the schedule in the administrator reducing, but not eliminating, the risk of url tampering or accidental processing.

Comment: cool! thanks! is there any documentation for this?

Comment: This is pretty weak protection -- user agent can be faked easily.

Comment: OK, looking at answer update I can say we have exact duplicate here.

Comment: perfect, thanks. I'm not so worried about purposeful manipulation - I'm more worried about one of our developers accidentally navigating to the page, so the http_agent should be fine

Answer (score 1):

I'd:

a) not expose your scripts to be requestable *at all* from your external-facing website;

b) set up a specific website for the tasks, eg tasks.yourdomain.com, which is only exposed on the local IP address.  No manner of spoofing or user-agent vagary is going to defeat that.  And it takes only a few min to set up.